# Power Bi - Filter on currency type

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have transactions in a variety of currencies in a Transaction table (columns TransactionAmount and TransactionCurrency), and also a related Currency table:

[image]

Using the column RateToEuro I have been able to convert all my transaction amounts, using a calculate column, into euros: 
[image]

An example of what I would like: I want to select in my report filter 'Dollar' and then the Transaction amount should convert all original transaction amounts to dollars. So in my example above, the $2052 original trx amount will be 2052 also in the 'Transaction amount ($)' column.

[EDIT:] 
Currently I have created measure that gets the filter value:

`CurrencyFilter = IF(LASTNONBLANK('CurrencyFormat'[Name], 1) = "USD", "USD", "EUR")`

And a calculated column that for each transaction calculates the converted transaction amount (depending on the report filter chosen):

`TransactionAmountConverted = CALCULATE(VALUES(Transactions[TransactionAmount]) * (IF([CurrencyFilter] = "EUR", VALUES('Currency'[RateToEuro]), VALUES('Currency'[RateToDollar]))))`

But for some reason the `IF` statement always returns `TRUE` (i.e. always uses the `RateToEuro` column).

Any hint or tip to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Added a small example of the desired outcome. I am actually quite far with figuring it out myself: I added a second Currency table that I use as a report filter. Then I am using the filter value in a calculated column using an `IF` statement. Did not get it to work fully yet though!

Answer (score -1):

Currently this is not possible in Power BI: it is not supported that a **calculated column** uses a slicer value.

A **measure** can be used to get the slicer value, but in this particular case (if one value for each row is required to be calculated), there is no solution possible unfortunately.